# preparing data into python readable format

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a file with 2 columns("IdNo", "skillsList") in a csv file. when I read the file. It reads the entire file as a string. IdNo has a serialNumber and skillsList has a list of user specified skills. So I want to find out the term frequency of the skills.

But my issue is how do I get the data into an accessible form. My data looks something like this.

```
>>> a1

'IdNo, skillsList\nBAXA0000206_NEENA_TIWARI_0.htm,"[u\'Training\', u\'E-Learning\', u\'PowerPoint\', u\'Teaching\', u\'Accounting\', u\'Team Management\', u\'Team Building\', u\'Microsoft Excel\', u\'Microsoft Office\', u\'Financial Accounting\', u\'Microsoft Word\', u\'Customer Service\']"\nBAXA0000227_ABDUR_RAZZAQUE_0.htm,"[u\'Telecommunications\', u\'Data Center\', u\'ISO 27001\', u\'Management\', u\'BS25999\', u\'Technology\', u\'Information Technology...\', u\'Certified PMP\\xae\', u\'Certified BS25999 Lead...\']"\nBAXA0000261_Priya _ Lobo_0.htm,"[u\'Market Research\', u\'Segmentation\', u\'Marketing Strategy\', u\'Consumer Behavior\', u\'Experience Working with...\']"
```

Need help.
Thanks

Comment: Read it with csv package provided by Python. Or use Pandas reader.

Comment: Alternatively look into 'split' function. Which will split your string by comma and put into list.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html or http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html

Answer (score 0):

This is my general routine for handling data in a form of string. It may not be well suited to your situation (where your string has a lot of symbols), but take a look won't harm, right?

The `split()` function splits a string into a list of strings, for example:

```
>>> a1 = 'id1, skill1\nid2, skill2\nid3, skill3'
>>> a2 = a1.split('\n')
>>> a2
>>> ['id1, skill1', 'id2, skill2', 'id3, skill3']
```

In this case, `a2` shows a list of rows. Take a step further to separate the two columns:

```
>>> a3 = [row.split(', ') for row in a2]
>>> a3
>>> [['id1', 'skill1'], ['id2', 'skill2'], ['id3', 'skill3']]
>>> for row in a3:
...     for col in row:
...             print col,
...     print ''
...
id1 skill1
id2 skill2
id3 skill3
```

To access all elements in each column, use the `zip()` function:

```
>>> a4 = zip(*a3)
>>> a4
>>> [('id1', 'id2', 'id3'), ('skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3')]
>>> for col in a4:
...     for row in col:
...             print row,
...     print ''
...
id1 id2 id3
skill1 skill2 skill3
```